# Primeng option filter in Datatable not work?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Option filter only works if word begins with selected letters

```
<p-column field="name" header="Name" filter="filter" filterDelay="500"></p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[filter]` is `Boolean` must be true or false ! If you want a custom filter, go check for template filter : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter